# How do they know an integral has no closed form solution?

Tags: terminology, closed-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

When they say that, e.g., Li(x) has no closed form (for some agreed upon definition of "closed form"), do they mean that it can be **proved** that there isn't one, or just that none has been found yet.  Most authors seem to just assert that a given integral can't be represented in any simpler way, but I've been wondering if that's because they know this for a fact, or just that it's assumed that if there is one it would have been found by now.

If this is a theorem, how would you go about proving it?

Comment: Joshua Frank, I'm sorry we had to close your first question on the site, but it looks like answers to the linked question should answer your question.  I hope you stick around, and if you have questions not resolved at the link, please feel free to ask them.

Comment: I guess that is a duplicate, but it's weird because I did search for an existing answer before posting and didn't come across the linked answer.  Not sure why it wasn't found.  Thanks for the link.